# Rx.Observable.prototype.skip is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have Angular 2 application with the following code:

```
  nextPage() {
    this.currentPage += 1;
    this.files = this._rawFiles
      .skip((this.currentPage - 1) * 100)
      .take(100);
  }
```

It returns the following error:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this._rawFiles.skip is not a function
```

`this._rawFiles` is produced by Angular's `Http` service, so it's supposed to use RxJS. Here's what it looks like when printed to the console:

[image: screenshot]

It seems to be an Observable, but only a few methods are present. Why isn't [`Rx.Observable.prototype.skip(count)`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/skip.md) in there?

Here's what a relevant part of `package.json` looks like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@angular2-material/card": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@angular2-material/checkbox": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@angular2-material/progress-circle": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@angular2-material/radio": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@angular2-material/sidenav": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "core-js": "^2.1.5",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.6"
  },
```

It's just a regular RxJS, not some kind of light version. Shouldn't it include all methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to include all methods, use:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

If you want to include only `skip()` method, use:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/skip';
```

Rx is designed to be modular, so that not all code is loaded into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/skip';
```

You can also import all at once using

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

but that defeats the purpose of the modularization and unnecessarily bloats your code output size.